# Override homepage controller in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am using http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/overriding_controllers.html as a reference when trying to override the homepage controller.

I tried the following in config.yml:

```
sylius_web:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        frontend:
            homepage:
                controller: SpaceDice\WebBundle\Controller\Frontend\HomepageController
```

And it doesn't seem to be working.

What would I put in config.yml to specify the controller from the homepage?

In: vendor/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/config/routing/main.yml I see:

```
sylius_homepage:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: sylius.controller.frontend.homepage:mainAction }
```

but I'm not sure how to override/set sylius.controller.frontend.homepage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out a couple ways to do this.

First, you can set the parameter in config.yml:

```
parameters: 
    sylius.controller.frontend.homepage.class: My\Controller\Here
```

Another option is to set the homepage route of / in my AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Frontend\Homepage:main }
```

Ensure that your routing config is processed before the Sylius WebBundle config (listed first in app/config/routing.yml) and you can take it from there.